# iOS: URL link in UITextField with different text

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to insert a URL hyperlink into a UITextField that has different display text.

This is super easy in html:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Go To Google</a>
```

How can I do this in iOS?

Comment: Does it have to be a UITextField? (i.e., is editing required?)

Comment: UITextFields can't detect links but textviews can automatically detect url's and open them in safari.

Comment: Editing is not required. The problem is that there is a lot of text, with the hyperlink at the bottom. I have to scroll through the text to get down to the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so here's what I did to get what I wanted. I used UIWebView, and simply linked it to an html page in the project that has the text, and hyperlink at the bottom with different text displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can *change* the text style inside your UITextField via an attributed string sent to the text field's ["`attributedText`" property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/attributedText).

However, what I suspect you *really* want to do is have a link that's clickable.  I would recommend using a UIButton with a custom type (i.e. no border) and you can set the color and the underline style.

But like Evan said, if you have multiple lines of text, it may be smarter to use a UITextField where you set "`editable`" to NO and turn on the LINK traits (both of these you can do from the object inspector in Xcode).

Comment: I should have added that this is a scrolling text field, i.e. lots of text. The hyperlink is at the bottom. Is there a way to attach a UIbutton to the bottom of a UItextfield?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here :

If you want it as clickable Hyperlink,

```
NSString *string = @"<a href=\"http://www.google.com/\">Go To Google</a>";
```

You need to add "BACKWARD SLASH" before ". That's it.